# Fetching list of user's friends for website

Tags: facebook-javascript-sdk

I have implemented Fb login for my website. Also for the Fb page of my app inside approved items it shows - user_friends
Provides access to a person's list of friends that also use your app. This permission is approved by default.

How can I get the list of friends of the user who is there on my app ?

Also When I try to do this --

```
FB.api(
    "/me/friends",
    function (response) {
     if (response && response.data){
        alert(response.data);
      } else {
        console.log('Something goes wrong', response);
      }
    }
);
```

I get no response.

Thanks,
Newbie

Answer (score 1):

First, you need to include and initialize the JavaScript SDK: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/javascript/quickstart/v2.2

Then, you need to authorize the user: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.login/v2.0

(don´t forget to use the scope parameter with the "user_friends" permission)

After that, you can call F`B.api('/me/friends'...` to get the **friends of the user who authorized the App too**.

You can also test `/me/friends` in the API Explorer, just select the correct App: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/?method=GET&path=me%2Ffriends&version=v2.2

Comment: Including JS SDK and authorization.. this all i did ..
the problem is with  FB.api('/me/friends' ..)

Comment: well, did any of your facebook friends authorize the app too?

Comment: what do you get exactly by using console.log(response)?

Comment: should I use tagged friends and check the response ?

Comment: no, tagged friends is for tagging only, and you would need to go through review too

Comment: the response of console.log(response) is  ---
the page at XXXXX.com say:

Comment: check out the browser console in general. and if possible, present a test link. i am pretty sure there´s just no friend who authorized your app too.

Comment: browser console is -- Object {data: Array[0], summary: Object}

Comment: well, i am pretty sure there are no friends authorized then. looks like a correct response, and there´s probably a "total_count" in the summary object too.

Comment: i don't knw.. as i have friends authorized to app .. i myself authorized the app and when I asked one of my fb friend to login to the same code it didnt work ..

Comment: "it didn´t work" - so he is NOT logged in. you may need to set your app public in the settings.